# Manipulating Data Frame in R by ID

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I have a data frame:

```
ID      date     term   estimate
unit1 1/1/2015 intercept 1.01
unit1 1/1/2015 x1        2.01
unit1 1/1/2015 x2        3.01
unit1 1/1/2015 x3        4.01
unit1 1/1/2015 x4        5.01
unit2 1/1/2015 intercept 1.01
unit2 1/1/2015 x1        -1.01
unit2 1/1/2015 x2        1.01
unit2 1/1/2015 x3        2.01
unit1 1/2/2015 intercept 1.01
unit1 1/2/2015 x1        2.01
unit1 1/2/2015 x2        3.01
unit1 1/2/2015 x3        4.01
unit1 1/2/2015 x4        5.01
```

What I am trying to get is each each term in its own column, by ID and date, with NAs for the ID and Date combinations that do not have a certain term associated with it. So, there should be a total of 7 columns- ID, date, intercept, and x1-x4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple reshaping from long to wide problem

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(df, ID + date ~ term)
#      ID     date intercept    x1   x2   x3   x4
# 1 unit1 1/1/2015      1.01  2.01 3.01 4.01 5.01
# 2 unit1 1/2/2015      1.01  2.01 3.01 4.01 5.01
# 3 unit2 1/1/2015      1.01 -1.01 1.01 2.01   NA
```

Comment: This worked, however I have more than one column associated with each term (I have columns for an estimate, lower bound and upper bound). Any way to get the two other columns into the improved data frame?

Comment: You probably need to add them to the formula. I can't tell for sure without seeing the actual data.

Answer (score 2):

Or

```
library(tidyr)
spread(df1, term, estimate)
#     ID     date intercept    x1   x2   x3   x4
#1 unit1 1/1/2015      1.01  2.01 3.01 4.01 5.01
#2 unit1 1/2/2015      1.01  2.01 3.01 4.01 5.01
#3 unit2 1/1/2015      1.01 -1.01 1.01 2.01   NA
```